# Email process in Hybris not working

Tags: email, sap-commerce-cloud

I am a newbie to Hybris and I got a task to configure mail service in the application.
The code for the mail is already written but still the mail is not working.
I tried to configure it and the smtp configuration is fine. I am using SMTP configuration of Google.
However, when I execute the process, it breaks at the very first node quoting :

```
Something Went Wrong
```

I am using the following link :

```
http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/index.php/ecommerce-with-hybris-sending-emails/

<process xmlns="http://www.hybris.de/xsd/processdefinition"
         start="generateOneMillionPurchaseEmail"
         name="oneMillionPurchaseProcess"
         processClass="com.project.model.OneMillionPurchaseProcessModel"
         onError="error">

    <action id="generateOneMillionPurchaseEmail" bean="generateOneMillionPurchaseEmail">
        <transition name="OK" to="sendEmail"/>
        <transition name="NOK" to="error"/>
    </action>
```

This is the very first node : generateOneMillionPurchaseEmail
but when I execute it, its not working.

Can anyone suggest anything on how to get it done ?

Comment: do you have any log?

Comment: Try this : https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/sending-emails-in-hybris/

Answer (score 0):

First guess without any logs:

get fakeSMTP (https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/) and try to it as a local service by setting the value

```
mail.smtp.server=127.0.0.1
```

As google requires a authentication to use there SMTP Service, a local version without any authentication would be a good first test.